# What’s the difference between "How can I help you?"and "How can we help you?"

Tags: meaning-in-context, speech, royal-we

I heard this expression in a video about buying clothes.

In that video, the shop-keeper welcomed the customer by saying "How can we help you?", even though the shopkeeper was the only salesperson in the store- there was no '*we*' to help.

So, why did he say"How can **we** help you?" instead of "How can **I** help you?"

Are these two interchangeable? Or is this a special phrase? If they're not interchangeable, is there some sort of rule or distinction to keep in mind?

Comment: Presumably he was speaking for the shop as a business.

Comment: Some call it [*the royal "we"*](https://youtu.be/dzGuQ5XuRAU?t=8).

Comment: Yes, they're interchangeable in that context. Same as I can say "we can say X".

Comment: @TusharRaj The "royal we" is rather different. There is a convention that monarchs refer to themselves in the plural as a matter of status, a bit like the way that English used to, and most other European languages still do, use the second person plural rather than the second person singular when speaking to an individual of higher social status.

Answer (score 1):

As Ms. Bunting has already explained in a comment, *we* here stands for the business as a whole, which involves other people, even though they are not currently on the premises. The idea conveyed by *we* is that the work of all these people contributes to the help that the customer is about to receive.